# Update the person details based on the person that the user clicks in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement search funtionallity where a name is searched and drop down appears with names along with more button(means that on clicking on more button it shows details of that particular person by navigating to another page)For now everything working fine but I want to update the details based on the name selected by the user(for now only name).(Details are present in another file.)

This below code is for Search

```
     export default function Search() {
          const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
          const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
          const routes = [{ path: "/details", element: <Details /> }];
          const handleSearch = (e) => {
            const searchTerm = e.target.value;
             setSearchTerm(searchTerm);
    
            // Filter the financial professionals based on the search input
            const filteredResults = CAData.filter((professional) =>
              professional.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            );
            setSearchResults(filteredResults);
          };
          return (
            <>
              <div>
                <form>
                  <div className="relative flex ">
                    <input
                      type="search"
                      id="default-search"
                       className="max-sm:w-72 text-bold mt-14 block w-96 p-4 pl-6 text-sm text- 
          gray-900 border  rounded-2xl bg-white focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 "
                      placeholder="Search by name"
                      required
                      value={searchTerm}
                       onChange={handleSearch}
                    />
                    <div className=" h-14 w-36 bg-sky-600 text-white font-semibold pl-12 text-sm  
        flex mt-14 -ml-4 pointer-events-none rounded-xl  ">
                      <button>Search</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div>
                {/* Display search results */}
                <ul>
                  {searchResults.map((result) => (
                    <li key={result.id} className="flex justify-between">
                      <h3>{result.name}</h3>
                      <Link to={`/details`}>
                        <button>more</button>
                      </Link>
                      {/* Add more details as needed */}
                    </li>
                   ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
    
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/details" element={<Details />} />
              </Routes>
            </>
          );
        }
```

```
 This code is for details of that person(full code is skipped)



 export default function Details() {
          return (
        <>
          <div className="mt-20 ">
            <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-60">
              <div>
                <div className="p-6 w-96">
                  <h1 className="font-bold text-2xl">{ }</h1> //What should be used in the empty bracket and how to import the name of the person that user choose.
                  <p>
                        .
                        .
                        .
```